# Ruby on Rails Paperclip Association Dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have a bug happening with Paperclip in an RoR site.  I have an association control in a form and the max size in Paperclip set to 1 MB.  When a user breaks this limit, it will cause the association box to have simply Yes and No as the options and causes a major error if the user submits the page with a new, smaller file.  I have seen reports of bugs when the size is exceeded, but not this specific one.  Image uploading works normally as long as a user is under the limit.

**Models**

```
class Vehicle < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :vehicle_location
  has_many :reservations
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "320x240>", thumb: "32x24>"}
  validates_attachment :image,
                         content_type: { content_type: ['image/jpeg',
                        'image/jpg', 'image/png', 'image/gif'] },
                         size: { less_than: 1.megabytes }
end

class VehicleLocation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :vehicles
end
```

**View**

```
<%= f.association :vehicle_location, label: false, :collection =>
  @vehicle_locations, :prompt => "Select Location", :wrapper_html => 
  { :style => 'display: inline' } %>

<%= f.file_field :image, label: "Upload an image" %>
```

**Vehicle Param Values**

```
"vehicle"=>{"unit_number"=>"TEST123", "car_year"=>"2015", "car_make"=>"Ford", "car_model"=>"Test", "vin_number"=>"123456123456", "average_mileage"=>"", "odometer"=>"0", "next_service"=>"3000", "vehicle_location_id"=>"1", "image"=>#ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x46f2480 @original_filename="test.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"vehicle[image]\"; filename=\"test.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#File:C:/Users/Test~1/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20150921-460-8hrte0>>, "is_serviced"=>"0", "is_archived"=>"0"}
```

I have also tried using a collection_select, but when i do I get an error

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VehiclesController#create

VehicleLocation(#47412924) expected, got String(#19395840).
```

Comment: Can you show your association definitions for each model?

Comment: I've put the full code for both models in.  Wouldn't be surprised if I'm just missing something.

Comment: can you give us the value contained in the params for the key `params[:vehicle]` (I am pretty sure you get a String for the `params[:vehicle][:vehicle_location_id]` instead of an ID. Also, the problem is not related with Paperclip

Comment: Uhh...don't know what happened here.  I put in debug(params) to get the values, which I put in the question.  However, after I did that the association box works normally, even after I removed debug line from it.  I didn't touch anything else.

Comment: D'oh! Found the error.  @vehicle_locations wasn't defined everywhere it needed to be in the controller.  I fixed this while trying to get the collection_select to work, which for whatever reason still would not.  When I went back to an association, worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vehicle_locations was not defined in the create or update methods in the controller (was in new/edit).  It only gave the impression that this was a Paperclip issue because the Paperclip rejection was the only thing that would trigger it.